# Can't import AVFoundation.framework, so app can't play music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

I a new to xcode, and trying to make a very simple app for playing a noise upon a button being clicked. I asked a previous quesiton in which I had an error and the user's suggested that I wasn't properly importing the AVFoundation.framework. I took their suggestion and set up the import statement, but now get an error. Please see my code below:

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sampleText;
@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface FirstViewController ()
@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize sampleText = _sampleText;

- (IBAction)beep:(UIButton *)sender {
       NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                   pathForResource:@"button1"
                                                   ofType:@"mp3"]];
        AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
        [click play];
    //[click release];
}
```

However, upon building, I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone please help me resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also have to add the AVFoundation framework to your project. Click on the project at the top of the source list on the left, select your target, go to the Summary pane, and click the "+" button under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the framework as well.  Click on your project in the left column, scroll down to frameworks and click add. Find the a framework you need.